# Checking SNMP 2v availability

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I have a problem with checking if SNMP Manager is installed on a given server. I had an idea to send a request locally because some part of the OIDs are constant, but for that you need a community - and this doesn't have to be constant. Therefore, before I start sending requests to SNMP agents, I would like to check if SNMP is installed on the service at all.

I miss any ideas - I would be grateful for tips, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: @Amessihel I don't have any idea how to check it - I am not expecting ready code, I would only really appreciate any advice how to check it. Sending request for itself without community password is impossible, so I don't have another idea how to check it.

Comment: For SNMPv2 requests with wrong community names, the agent has a chance to reply with AuthorizationError (16) responses (different from v1 where there is no such error type). So you should simply send a request with common names like "public" and see what response you might get. However, the agent might be configured to reply nothing (based on the vendor implementation).

Comment: @LexLi no I can't handle it, because when SNMP service is off, then the thread is stopping and nothing is returning at all - I can't even check if the variable is not or noll